# Vercel/Next.js 13: New pages 404 on Link/router.push but work directly

Tags: next.js, vercel

Website works fine in general and all existing pages work as intended.

When adding new pages they work fine on localhost/dev, but when pushed to Vercel they don't.
I can access them directly via their URL, but if I follow a Link-tag or router.push to them, they return af 404. If I click refresh on the 404, they load fine.

When 404 is triggered I see no errors in the server logs and the clients console just logs:

```
GET https://DOMAIN/_next/data/1ja0i7_5sn-xTJFHhWwsk/test-ssr.json 404
GET https://DOMAIN/_next/data/1ja0i7_5sn-xTJFHhWwsk/404.json 404
```

For example I can replicate it by creating these two scripts and trying to click the links between them:

test-ssr.js:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function Page(props) {
  return(
    <>
      Test: {props.test}<br/>
      <Link href='/test-static/'>Link Static</Link>
    </>
  )
}
 
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return { props: { test: 'OK' } }
}
 
export default Page
```

test-static.js:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      Test static: OK<br/>
      <Link href='/test-ssr/'>Link SSR</Link>
    </>
  )
}
```

Tried different filenames for the pages, tried copying a working page to a new file, tried adding prefetch={false} on the inbound links, tried manually redeploying in Vercel UI to avoid build cache, tried clearing Vercel Data Cache, tried upgrading Next 13.2.3>13.4.10. Nothing helped.

I feel stupid, as if I am missing something obvious. Is there any route caching or other cache that I can clear or similar?

Any advice on how to debug or what to try?